# How can I copy a model from one collection to another in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, deep-copy, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to copy a model from a backbone collection to another but problem is that only reference is being copies, that is if I change value of model in one collection the value is automatically changed for other collection. The problem is how do I make an exact copy of model object.

Thanks

Comment: Try creating a deep copy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the methods of cloning but the result was not good because cid of the clonned model was becoming same which was causing problem. So I have applied this method

```
var widget = this.widgetsCollection.get(widgetId)
var newWidget=new Widget(widget.attributes);
```

This gives a copy with different cid.

[image]

Comment: or `new Widget(this.widgetsCollection.get(widgetId).toJSON())`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a deep copy, which will create a new object instance with the same values.

An example can be found in this SO thread: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

There also exist a method clone in Backbone Model that creates a new copy with same attributes

```
this.widgetsActiveCollection.add(widget.clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I create a deep copy of the model

```
var newModel = new createModel(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldModel)));
newCollection.add(newModel );
```